# Como agrupar botões dentro de uma coluna em uma table de maneira que não sofram alterações quando a coluna for ajustada

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, html5, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho uma table que possui 4 botões de ação dentro de uma célula de uma coluna. Quando os nomes começam a ficar com tamanho maior de caracteres, a tabela começa a se auto-ajustar e na coluna Ações, os 4 botões ficam soltos e alguns deles começam a descer para a linha inferior mesmo tendo espaço de sobra na largura da célula da coluna. Existe uma maneira de colocá-los, tipo, dentro de algum objeto para que fiquem sempre alinhados conforme a largura da célula?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
.align-center {
    text-align: center;
    /*max-width: 80px*/
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione `white-space: nowrap;` à coluna da tabela. O `nowrap` impede que espaços em branco quebrem para a próxima linha.

Exemplo sem `white-space: nowrap;`:

```css
.icones{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 25px;
   height: 25px;
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<table width="50%" border="1">
   <tr>
      <td width="50">
         1
      </td>
      <td>
         Jurídica
      </td>
      <td>
         nome nome nome nome
      </td>
      <td>
         nome nome nome nome nome nome nome nome
      </td>
      <td align="center">
         <span class="icones"></span>
         <span class="icones"></span>
         <span class="icones"></span>
         <span class="icones"></span>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Exemplo com `white-space: nowrap;`:

```css
.icones{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 25px;
   height: 25px;
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<table width="50%" border="1">
   <tr>
      <td width="50">
         1
      </td>
      <td>
         Jurídica
      </td>
      <td>
         nome nome nome nome
      </td>
      <td>
         nome nome nome nome nome nome nome nome
      </td>
      <td align="center" style="white-space: nowrap;">
         <span class="icones"></span>
         <span class="icones"></span>
         <span class="icones"></span>
         <span class="icones"></span>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Mano, funcionou 100%! Obrigado :))))))